# how to implement a transparent backgound webapp among process

Tags: android, html, web-applications, firefox-os

all
I like to implement a webapp for realtime debugging like "android->developer options->show touch data" or "android->developer options->show CPU usage".
But, I can't found any proper method for this with HTML5(and some of hybrid framework)
I also understand this overlay scheme is highly depend on underlying platform(like android, tizen, firefox-os).

is there any way or idea to implement a transparent background webapp among process?
my first target platform is android.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For firefoxOS it's been done in system so it's not possible.

For android there's [Tooleap SDK](http://www.geektime.com/2014/09/08/make-your-apps-float-with-the-tooleap-sdk/) that allow you to develop float window app, but I have no idea if it support writing in HTML5.